# Как исправить ошибки в позиционировании при верстке макета?

Tags: html, css

Смешались два блока в макете. Как исправить? Тот, который розовый, должен идти сразу за блоком, который оказался под ним.

https://jsfiddle.net/edryb3c6/ `[2]`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Переставить контейнер `.right-side` выше контейнера `.footer` наверное.

https://jsfiddle.net/edryb3c6/2/

```css
/*acc*/

.seventh-part {
  margin-bottom: 50em;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.seventh-part_s {
  height: 100%;
  width: 70.714em;
  padding-left: 18em;
  display: block;
}
.accordion {
  padding-top: 2em;
  // overflow: hidden; 
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.boy {
  width: 32em;
  height: 23.000em;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
.look .info-icons_big-text {
  display: none;
}
.info {
  width: 35.714em;
  height: 23.000em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
.info-icons {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 0.08em solid #e5e5e5;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.info-icons_same {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 1.863em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.info-icons_big-header {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.info-icons_big-text {
  border-bottom: 0.08em solid #e5e5e5;
  border-right: 0.08em solid #e5e5e5;
  border-left: 0.08em solid #e5e5e5;
  height: 10em;
}
.info-icons_text {
  display: block;
  font-family: roboto_light_italic;
  font-size: 1.000em;
  color: #b6b6b6;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-right: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
/*футер*/

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 31.250em;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
}
.footer-s {
  width: 70.714em;
  // position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 31.250em;
}
.left-side {
  width: 22em;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.central {
  width: 22em;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.right-side {
  width: 22em;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.logo-q {
  font-size: 3.250em;
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
  color: #cccccc;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.left-text {
  font-family: roboto_regular;
  font-size: 1.250em;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: justify;
}
.followers {
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.188em;
  font-family: Montserrat-Bold;
}
.blog {
  color: black;
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  font-size: 1.188em;
}
.blogs {
  width: 100%;
  height: 9em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.blogs-pics {
  width: 6.316em;
  height: 4.211em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.big-text {
  font-family: Montserrat-Regular;
  font-size: 1.000em;
  color: black;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
}
.data {
  font-family: roboto_light_italic;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="seventh-part">
  <span class="one">Service</span>
  <span class="two">WHAT WE DO</span>
  <span class="no-text_no">_____</span>
  <div class="seventh-part_s">
    <span class="three">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</span>
    <div class="accordion">
      <img class="boy" src="images/43.jpg" alt="#">
      <div class="info">
        <div class="look" onclick="toogle(this)">
          <div class="info-icons">
            <img class="info-icons_same" src="images/PICTURE.png" alt="#">
            <h2 class="info-icons_big-header">PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="info-icons_big-text">
            <span class="info-icons_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime nobis libero assumenda ut. Praesentium et fugiat eaque, quaerat ut voluptate dolorem magnam totam distinctio eveniet, hic dolores corporis, voluptatum sint.
      </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="look" onclick="toogle(this)">
          <div class="info-icons">
            <img class="info-icons_same" src="images/EQUALIZER.png" alt="#">
            <h2 class="info-icons_big-header">CREATIVITY</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="info-icons_big-text">
            <span class="info-icons_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime nobis libero assumenda ut. Praesentium et fugiat eaque, quaerat ut voluptate dolorem magnam totam distinctio eveniet, hic dolores corporis, voluptatum sint.
      </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="look" onclick="toogle(this)">
          <div class="info-icons">
            <img class="info-icons_same" src="images/BULLSEYE.png" alt="#">
            <h2 class="info-icons_big-header">WEB DESIGNE</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="info-icons_big-text">
            <span class="info-icons_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime nobis libero assumenda ut. Praesentium et fugiat eaque, quaerat ut voluptate dolorem magnam totam distinctio eveniet, hic dolores corporis, voluptatum sint.
      </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- FOOOOTER -->

  <div class="right-side">
    <h1 class="insta">INSTAGRAM</h1>
    <img class="lie" src="images/final.jpeg" alt="#">
    <a class="links" href="#">View more photos</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-s">
      <div class="left-side">
        <h1 class="logo-q">MoGo</h1>
        <span class="left-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique possimus impedit, est harum laboriosam maxime blanditiis sunt veniam quam nam quos dolores aspernatur sed repellendus dolor accusantium, expedita animi nemo.</span>
        <span class="followers">15K followers</span>
      </div>
      <div class="central">
        <h1 class="blog">BLOGS</h1>
        <div class="blogs">
          <img class="blogs-pics" src="images/N.jpeg" alt="#">
          <h1 class="big-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
          <p class="data">Jun 9, 2016</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blogs">
          <img class="blogs-pics" src="images/photos.jpeg" alt="#">
          <h1 class="big-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
          <p class="data">Jun 9, 2016</p>
        </div>
        <div class="blogs">
          <img class="blogs-pics" src="images/Fyn.jpeg" alt="#">
          <h1 class="big-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</h1>
          <p class="data">Jun 9, 2016</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: это часть футера, она не должна быть выше него